# How to implement Google IMA into videojs?

Tags: video.js, double-click-advertising, google-ima

I am struggling implementing and generating my `adTagUrl` into my demo example.

```
var options = {
  id: 'content_video',
  //adTagUrl: 'http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?sz=640x480&' +
    //  'iu=/124319096/external/ad_rule_samples&ciu_szs=300x250&ad_rule=1&' +
     // 'impl=s&gdfp_req=1&env=vp&output=xml_vmap1&unviewed_position_start=1&' +
     // 'cust_params=sample_ar%3Dpremidpostpod%26deployment%3Dgmf-js&cmsid=496&' +
     // 'vid=short_onecue&correlator='
   adTagUrl: 'https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?sz=640x480&iu=/265894175/Video&impl=s&gdfp_req=1&env=vp&output=vast&unviewed_position_start=1&url=[referrer_url]&description_url=[description_url]&correlator=[timestamp]'      
};
```

As you can see the `adTagUrl`s are somewhat different and the one I use does not show any ads while the example `adTagUrl` works flawlessly.

The error message I receive is:

```
AdsLoader error: AdError 1009: The VAST response document is empty.
```

How do I generate one out of my Doubleclick dashboard or how do I configure it to work with videojs?

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IMA team hosts a [VideoJS implementation on GitHub](https://github.com/googleads/videojs-ima) that you can modify and use.

As for the error 1009 (empty VAST), there can be many reasons. Make sure your ad tag actually returns a meaningful VAST response if you open it in a browser. If it doesn't serve only in your implementation, you might need to reset IMA by following [this instruction](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/faq#8) and possibly [this](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/faq#12) as well.

Comment: You can also check in VAST Inspector here:
https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/vastinspector

Comment: @StevenMelendez, the VAST Inspector doesn't use VideoJS as the video player.

Comment: Neither does opening VAST tag in native browser. I was responding to your 'Make sure your ad tag returns a meaningful VAST response if you open it in a browser'. That is platform independent.

Comment: Indeed, but it's a good way to rule out any implementation issue by making sure the tag actually returns a VAST response as opposed to an empty document. Sometimes implementations do play a factor causing the ad server to return empty VAST responses.

Comment: Which is also why you should do both. One to check implementation, but vast inspector is a google tool to directly test the actual ad content. You can have a VAST tag that returns valid XML but invalid creatives or companions. It will let you know. I totally agree with you to do a base browser check, but recommend to always remember both.